# Why does scroll wheel input only work in the alternate case

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I have an array of weapons that I'm trying to cycle through using the scroll wheel. I have code but it will only scroll from the lowest index to the highest index in one move (overflow), but it won't go one by one counting up through the array. Here is my code

```
void Update()
{
    var d = Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel");     //ScrollWheel Input
    if (d > 0f)
    {
        activeWeaponIndex = (activeWeaponIndex + 1 < weapons.Length) ? activeWeaponIndex++ : activeWeaponIndex = 0; //Increment index, if at max set to 0
    }
    else if (d < 0f)
    {
        activeWeaponIndex = (activeWeaponIndex - 1 >= 0) ? activeWeaponIndex-- : activeWeaponIndex = 3; //Increment index unless it is at min then set to 3(4th wep)
    }

    Swap(activeWeaponIndex);        //Switch Weapon
}
```

Comment: Because update is called every frame and the duration of your scroll action will happen over multiple frames, causing your code to be called multiple times.

Comment: akaBase is probably right, but I also see a different problem: `activeWeaponIndex  = activeWeaponIndex ++` doesn't change the value of `activeWeaponIndex` . That would be `activeWeaponIndex  = ++activeWeaponIndex` ;

Comment: also also `activeWeaponIndex = (activeWeaponIndex+1) % weapons.Length;` and `activeWeaponIndex = (activeWeaponIndex+weapons.Length-1) % weapons.Length`

Comment: @PalleDue Thankyou that was the problem

Comment: Glad to hear. I've added my suggestion as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make sure you increase/decrease the activeWeaponIndex before assigning the value. Generally doing `x = x++` will not change the value of `x`.
And you are using the ternary operator wrong. It should be:

```
x = (conditional) ? value1 : value2
```

You are doing:

```
x = (conditional) ? value1 : statement1
```

You are, however, being saved by the fact that an assignment statement returns the value of the rgiht hand side.

You can change your code to this:

```cs
void Update()
{
    var d = Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel");     //ScrollWheel Input
    if (d > 0f)
    {
        activeWeaponIndex = (activeWeaponIndex + 1 < weapons.Length) ? ++activeWeaponIndex : 0; //Increment index, if at max set to 0
    }
    else if (d < 0f)
    {
        activeWeaponIndex = (activeWeaponIndex - 1 >= 0) ? --activeWeaponIndex : 3; //Decrement index unless it is at min then set to 3(4th wep)
    }

    Swap(activeWeaponIndex);        //Switch Weapon
}
```

**Edit:**
After Draco18snolongertrustsSE's good comment here is another version:

```cs
void Update()
{
    var d = Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel");     //ScrollWheel Input
    if (d==0)
    {
        return;
    } 
    activeWeaponIndex = (d > 0f) ? 
        activeWeaponIndex = (activeWeaponIndex + 1) % weapons.Length :
        activeWeaponIndex + (weapons.Length-1) % weapons.Length;

    Swap(activeWeaponIndex);        //Switch Weapon
}
```

It also avoids changing weapon if `d` equals 0.

Comment: `activeWeaponIndex = (activeWeaponIndex+1) % weapons.length` makes the ternary obsolete. And removes the hard-coded reliance on the length of the array to be always 4.

Comment: @Draco18snolongertrustsSE: You're right. I've added a more terse version that takes this into account.

Comment: You can still simplify, if you're going to put the ternary where you have. `activeWeaponIndex = (activeWeaponIndex + (d > 0f ? 1 : -1) + weapons.Length) % weapons.Length;`  (Note: the `+weapons.Length` can go where it is because when adding `+1`, it doesn't change anything: index = 2, add 1, add 4, (total 7), mod 4 is still 3).